# Getting user input from multiple editText, then store in ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-edittext

I have 4 editText, and I want to store all the values in `String` arrayList. I have declared my `arrayList` globally. I can get the correct size of my `arrayList`, but I can't get any `String` value. Here's my code:

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
        {
            //get the user name
            String player1 = editText.getText().toString();
            playerName.add(player1);
        }
        return false;
    }
});
editText1.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
        {
            //get the user name
            playerName.add(editText.getText().toString());
        }
        return false;
    }
});
editText2.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
        {
            //get the user name
            playerName.add(editText.getText().toString());
        }
        return false;
    }
});
editText3.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
        {
            //get the user name
            playerName.add(editText.getText().toString());
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: post full code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, correct the listener, you use the same `editText` everywhere when you get the text `editText.getText().toString()`.

Note : You could update this to use 1 instance of listener but that a different question.

To read a List, use `List.get(int)` or iterate it like

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i){
    String s = list.get(i);
    ...
}
```

or

```
for(String s : list){
    ...
}
```

Now, did you need to use a listener, or could you just get the value when you need it ? That your project but that's an idea. Because did you want to stack the value if you input a value twice in the same `EditText`?

Comment: thanks for help, the error was typo :D actually I want to get the value once. Because I am passing this value to other activity by intent. So I am using those editText as login.

Comment: @AybarsKızılay remove those listener and simply call the `editText#.getText().toString()` when you want to submit the intent, you can always check the content first but you don't need to use those listeners.

Answer (score 0):

To get a single player, please try this code:

```
String player1 = playerName.get(0);
```

To get all the players from the list, please use this code:

```
for (String player : playerName) {
    Log.d("TAG", player);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
playerName.get(index);
```

you can get the string object you need from ArrayList in this way

Comment: yes, I have tried it. playerName.size() gives me correct result but I am not able to use playerName.get(0) or any index.

Comment: do you know that the editText's text will be added to your arrayList only after Done button from keyboard is pressed

Comment: yes, I know that. There was a syntax error, now everything is working. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
//declare global
ArrayList<EditText> editextList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> editextValuesList = new ArrayList<>();

onCreate(){
    //bind edittext and then
    editextList.add(editText);
    editextList.add(editText1);
    editextList.add(editText2);
    editextList.add(editText3);


     //you can use below lines anywhere if any text changes in edittext then it will give you updated text
     for(int i=0;i<edittextList.size();i++){
         String editTextString = edittextList.get(i).getText().toString();
         editextValuesList.add(editTextString);

     }

}
```